# Windows 7 Home Premiume error 2203

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, anti-virus

Running Windows 7 Home Premium. I'm trying to install turbo tax and my computer will not allow, in fact I haven't been able to either download or install anything for several months now. I read prior Error 2203 install post: I clicked on the install.exe for product I'm trying to install as instructed in your previous post, running as admin. Completed soft and hard boot. Ran as administrator, granted all with admin. Install config looks correct. I cannot understand WHAT anti-virus is blocking this because all either temporarily disabled or uninstalled. For the Windows Defender, I checked allow all settings prior to turning it off just in case.  What suggestions might you have...

Comment: This error usually occurs when Office Setup cannot access the default temporary folder in Windows (%temp%). A third-party program may restrict access to this folder, or there may not be sufficient permissions assigned to it. Check this link for further information http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2000547

Answer (score 0):

I googled "error 2203 windows 7"

And came up with this solution by a9fc at [sevenforums.com.](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/63211-how-i-solved-error-2203-a.html) I did not see you mention this particular attack at the problem.

"(For Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. Should be the same for other versions)

Yes.

It's the Pain In The A.. problem

I think I managed to solve it!

Apparently, you must have Permissions set for 'SYSTEM' in 2 Temp Folders.

They are:

C:\Windows\Installer

AND

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp

It seems that not having set the right permissions set in any of these folders will not allow microsoft installer to read the files, even though they are already inside.

So, they work in tandem:

I had an error that stated that it was the file in C:\Windows\Installer that could not be read.

Well, I checked and full control was given to 'SYSTEM' in the installer folder, but the problem was fixed after I gave 'SYSTEM' permissions for the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp

How to add permissions:

1. Right click folder - Properties - Security tab
2. In 'Group or usernames', you should have 1. Your account name and 2. SYSTEM
3. If SYSTEM is missing, click 'Edit...', then 'Add...'
4. In 'Enter object names to select', key in 'SYSTEM' then click OK
5. Click on 'SYSTEM' and make sure 'Full Control' is checked in the permissions window

If you can't find the folders

You'll need to show them hidden folders.

1. Open any window...IE 'My Computer'
2. Click Organise -> Folder and Search Options -> View -> Check 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives'

So, try this before you do a complete reinstall windows 7. I actually did a complete reinstall, only to have the same problem again after 2 weeks....I wonder what causes it.

Anyway, hope I helped.

---

Update 31/8/10:

1. You may have to do this again after certain updates have been applied for windows. You'd think the patches are created to solve problems like this lol.
2. Use this to solve other problems where the installer just quits for no reason. I believe it also helps if you have problems uninstalling certain programs. I've used this to solve the following:

a. Games for Windows Live installation
b. Nvidia driver '..The NVIDIA Control Panel could not be installed..' 
c. Installation for Folding@home

Do add a list of problems that you have solved in this thread so that others may find it. Thanks "

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

For sure it's a permissions error, often related to the Temp folder - but unless you have been playing with permissions yourself, first thing to wonder is how & why they were changed.

Microsoft say you can safely change the perms for that folder to 'Everyone - Full Control' but I'd still want to check why it happened & test/fix all other default permissions, as that may not be the only one.

*Prepare to spend at least half a day to do this properly. Though you can work at the same time, for most of it*

First, I'd run ad cleaners & good malware cleaners  - these are all freeware
[AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)
[JRT [Junkware Removal Tool]](http://thisisudax.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/junkware-removal-tool-jrt-by-thisisu.html)
[Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org)
[HitMan Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro)

& note that Windows Defender or Microsoft Security Essentials barely qualify as 'antivirus' - get something better in the long-run.

Then, once you know you're as clean as possible, use the [Windows Repair (All in One)](http://www.tweaking.com) from tweaking.com - be sure to carefully follow their [Clean Boot instructions](http://www.tweaking.com/articles/pages/performing_a_proper_windows_clean_boot_on_xpvista78,1.html)

This is one of the simplest, non-techie ways to make sure your system at least has its default settings in crucial system areas.
I've never known it to break anything.
Just work through each tab, do as it says & go on to the next. You are quite safe to allow it to use its default options on each tab.
Most of the things it does can be done by Windows itself - it just does them for you without needing a degree in computer science.

The only sticking point may be if it finds anything it cannot fix itself when it runs `sfc /scannow`
If you find it reports unfixable errors at that point, finish the other tabs first, then come back here, edit your post with the error details & post a comment under this answer, then we can investigate further.

Other than that, just work through it - don't be in a hurry, it's not quick.

---

**If sfc /scannow finds unfixable errors**

It's simpler & less confusing to re-scan starting with an empty log, so…

- navigate to %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\ [you can copy/paste that into the Start menu & hit Enter
- Delete the file CBS.log
- Run sfc /scannow again

When it's finished…

- Open an Elevated Command Prompt (*simplest method* - Open the Start Menu, click on All Programs and Accessories, right click on Command Prompt, and click on Run as administrator. )
- At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER: `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"` 
  Note The Sfcdetails.txt file contains details from every time that the System File Checker tool has been run on the computer. The file includes information about files that were not repaired by the System File Checker tool. Verify the date and time entries to determine the problem files that were found the last time that you ran the System File Checker tool.
  *This is why we deleted it first.*
- Open the Sfcdetails.txt file from your desktop.
  The Sfcdetails.txt file uses the following format: Date/Time SFC detail