# Windows 7: fix .exe issue but cannot access regedit.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm running Windows 7 Professional, SP1, 64 bit.

I tried to fix what I think is a corrupt regedit.exe file since almost all file associations do not work. Crucially, .exe won't work, and so I want to look into regedit.exe but cannot access it from cmd.exe (which was a heck to get started anyway)

[image: here]

As can be seen from the command prompt (when logged in as Administrator)

I tried:

- assoc .exe=exefile (the error: Permission denied (danish))
- regedit.exe (the error thrown in danish: No support for this interphase).

How can I get around this?

Comment: I'd be tempted to go straight for the full malware scan, then restore default perms - see my answer at http://superuser.com/questions/889980/windows-7-home-premiume-error-2203/890113#890113 for a full-blown work through.

Comment: You did not run `cmd.exe` **as** administrator. If you did, you would have `Administrator: Command prompt` in the title-bar. How did you start that command prompt?

Comment: @Rik, Ctrl+Alt+Del, then pressed Ctrl while started new job.

Comment: @Tetsujin, can this be done without exe executions; it seems like I need to run a lot of programs; that need .exe's (?!)

Comment: Did you try [this fix from microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2688326)?? It's for restoring the `.exe` association and is a `.msi` (so doesn't need .exe assoc.)

Comment: @Rik, yeah tried once but it didnt seem to install correctly. I will give it as try again.

Comment: @Rik, so after running the windows fix, the icons for regedit.exe now looks as expected but cannot get started still. And other exe icons still not working either.

Comment: Did you restart the computer? After that... you still can't run regedit.exe **as administrator** by typing `regedit` in the search/start and rightclicking `regedit.exe` and choosing `Run as administrator` ?? (It could be that the associations of .exe are still intact if "run as administrator" is chosen.)

Comment: Yes, restarted. And it says im Administrator. That said I dont get the right-click menu option "Run as administrator". When I left-click the regedit.exe it still complains with "the interphase is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a very bad malware on your PC.

Open your Windows explorer, navigate to `C:\Windows\system32` and make a copy of `regedit.exe`, e.g. to `regedit_copy.exe`.

Are you able to start the Registry Editor with the copied file?

If yes, then navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` and search for any `Debugger` Key in this sub-tree. Do you find anything?

Comment: No I could not start it. I got worried of the same (mal-ware, virus). I ended up completely reinstalling  windows. Did not wanted to take any chances.